# In Android 13, how can I type the tick character?

Tags: keyboard, android-13, special-chars

As the title says: How can I type the tick character (`´`) in usual Android devices (Android 13)? I haven't found a keyboard app yet that provides this character.

In Western Europe, the tick character character is not that unusual, and I have a few passwords that contain it. Changing those passwords at the respective servers would require them to be changed on multiple other client devices, too, which is not possible. So I have to enter them on every Android device that should be used to access those servers.

On the Android device, I could solve the problem by copying that character from a text in the browser into the clipboard and pasting it into the password text box from there. But this procedure is error prone and extremely annoying.

I am convinced that Android (as every other serious O/S) lets us enter not only this specific character, but Unicode characters in general. It's just that I am not able to find out how.

Comment: Similar to [Gboard: Set Custom Unicode Characters on Longpress or Add Custom Keyboard Keys or Layout](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224043/3573)

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing *which* Android keyboard you're using, a definitive answer is probably impossible. However, try pressing and holding similar keys. On several Android keyboards, such as Gboard and Samsung Keyboard, that produces menus of related characters: accented versions of letters, fractions for numbers, and so on. You may well find the tick that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and +1. Many Android version on many devices are affected by that problem. However, Android 13 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S9 Ultra currently bites me most. I have already tried what you have recommended, and I have tried more than five keyboard apps (all FOSS from f-droid), but to no avail.